# Backup using Dell powervault 124T

Tags: windows, backup, dell, symantec, dell-powervault

I connected my Dell PowerVault 124T to my Windows Server using SCSI cable, I set IP and Address mask for remote connection on my Dell device. I red on Dell page that Symantec Backup Exec is compatible software with my Dell PowerVault 124T. Is there any other (free) software that I can use with my Dell backup device, or Symantec is the only one?

If I buy Symantec software, do I need anything else, or I can backup my server immediately?

Answer (score 1):

searching for "opensource tape backup windows 2008" returns this: http://wiki.zmanda.com/index.php/Zmanda_Windows_Client

Answer (score 0):

15 seconds of googling found the device's product details stating "it supports leading 
applications from Symantec Backup Exec, Computer Associate Arcserve and CommVault Galaxy". None of these are free but it may even work with Server 2012's built in backup software, have you tried that?

Comment: No I didn't, but I think it is not supported by default Windows backup software!

Comment: win2008 backup doesn't work with TBUs at all afaik. IIRC it was somehow possible to take the old NTBackup utility from 2003 to 2008, but I'm a bit too lazy to google for a howto.